# Store in a javascript var a chunk of HTML stored in a Ruby variable

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby variable that has a chunk of html code stored on it, for example:

```
<html>
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></head>
 <body style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family:'Times New Roman'">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <div style="font-size:24px; font-family:'Times New Roman'">Jorge</div>
    <div style="font-size:15px; font-family:'Times New Roman'">Constanza</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, I have a variable in ruby called `html` that has that stored on it... (really it has \n \r at the end of lines) and I need a pass this ruby variable to a javascript var. So in my template.html.erb I have the following:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var previewHtml = "<%=html%>";
<% end %>
```

But this is not working as the following is rendered in my html file:

```
var previewHtml = "<html>
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></head>
 <body style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family:'Times New Roman'">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <div style="font-size:24px; font-family:'Times New Roman'">First Name</div>
    <div style="font-size:15px; font-family:'Times New Roman'">Last Name</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>";
```

And I'm getting in Firefox the following error: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal var previewHtml = "<html>`. That makes sense... and I have no idea hot to send this chunk of HTML to js. I need it to later be inserted in an iFrame.

I have already tried doing the following:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var previewHtml = "<%= @feed_template.html_template.gsub(/\r?\n/, '').html_safe %>";
<% end %>
```

And the following is rendered:

```
var previewHtml = "<html>  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></head>  <body style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family:'Times New Roman'"> <div style="text-align:center"> <div style="font-size:24px; font-family:'Times New Roman'">Jorge</div> <div style="font-size:15px; font-family:'Times New Roman'">Constanza</div> </div> </body> </html>";
```

And I'm getting a `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `escape_javascript` helper, which is aliased as `j`, too:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var previewHtml = "<%= escape_javascript html %>";
<% end %>
```

Or shorter:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var previewHtml = "<%= j html %>";
<% end %>
```

This replaces all special Javascript characters with their matching escape sequences, especially quotes, which seem to give you the most trouble.

The rendered result should then look like this: (Note the backslashes!)

```
var previewHtml = "<html>\n<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"  ... "
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent used ruby myself...and dont know how it works, but i assume it has a function for encoding json. So, you could save your html in a key-value variable and json_encode it.

In php, i output php variables into javascript using json_encode, like this

```
echo "window.json_data['" . $key . "'] = " . json_encode( $value ) . "\n";
```

where value can be your html string.